# Having "automatic" x

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Just a simple question (I imagine) but, lets say I have the following data file:

```
# no x data, it's sampled for instance each second.
23 42 48 
49 89 33
39 44 97
```

How (if possible) can I plot that as if it were

```
1 23 42 48 
2 49 89 33
3 39 44 97
```

using the 1,2,3,.. (first column) as x ?

doing something like: `plot "file.dat" using (lineNumber):3` for instance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

E.g. to plot the third line of the datafile:

```
plot "DATAFILE" u 3
```

or with `awk`:

```
plot "<awk '{print FNR,$0}' DATAFILE" u 1:4
```

Note that awk adds linenumbers, so the first column is linenumber.

does the same, gnuplot is automatically using the line-number for the x-axis

Answer (score 45):

If you don't want to rely on awk, gnuplot can do this as well.  See `help plot datafile using` and `help plot datafile using pseudocolumns`.
Try:

```
plot "file.dat" using (column(0)):3
```

Comment: You can even use `plot "file.dat" using 0:3`

Comment: Or, as pointed out in the other answer, even `plot "file.dat" using 3`

Comment: @vitaly -- Yep.  I used this (slightly more complicated) form because it allows for more complex expressions in the using expression (e.g. scaling of the line numbers, etc.) but for simple things you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 4):

Or more simply, you can also type: `plot "file.dat" u ($0):3`

This will allow you to modify the index variable linearly, as you would any other column

Such as scaling by 2 and adding 1: `plot "file.dat" u (($0)*2+1):3`