# GNUPlot : Graph CSV

Tags: linux, csv, gnuplot

I'm trying to print different curves with GNUPlot.

Here is my csv.

```
HP1,HP2,HP3,HP4,HP5
1703808,5175328,3337168,5696107,5708256
1107150,4364912,2324679,4475785,4830227 
2036,2844,16426,3336,3466
1393,2114,1898,2427,2878 
836,1678,1584,1288,1549 
448,835,441,934,1262
389,546,390,871,616 
38,86,64,101,97
```

I can graph on curve with this command :

```
plot "my_file.csv" using 0:1 with lines
```

I've on line and if i tried `0:2`, it prints this error

> warning: Skipping data file with no valid points - x range is invalid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having "automatic" x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664472/having-automatic-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first tell `gnuplot` that you have a `.csv` file:

```
set datafile separator ','
plot "my_file.csv" using 0:1 with lines
```

Then it should work fine. More details [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node173.html).